# Loop with PHP + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to create a map with markers, those markers location and content are stored in a database.

Here it is my code:

```
<?php

$query_map = "SELECT * FROM denuncias ORDER BY id";
$map_executa = mysql_query($query_map);
$lat = -1.456688;
$log = -48.477586;

?>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var map;


        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $lat ?>, <?= $log ?>);

        function init() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


            <?php    while ($map = mysql_fetch_object($map_executa)) { ?>
                  var contentString = '<div id="content" style="height: 200px;">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?= $map->titulo ?></h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<?= $map->descricao ?>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:  new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $map->lat ?>, <?= $map->log ?>),
      map: map,
      clickable: true,
      title: 'teste'
  });
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

              <?php } ?>

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        //]]>
        </script>
```

I'm able to get the markers at their correct positions, but the content is always the same: the last row.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Delivered source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Ver denúncias</title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
    <style type="text/css">
  body {
      background: #3f51b5 !important;
  }
  </style>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var map;


        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.456688, -48.477586);

        function init() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


                              var contentString = '<div id="content" style="height: 200px;">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Nanana</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      'Teste'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:  new google.maps.LatLng(-1.458780, -48.480526),
      map: map,
      clickable: true,
      title: 'teste'
  });
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

                                var contentString = '<div id="content" style="height: 200px;">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Teste 2</h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:  new google.maps.LatLng(-1.471875, -48.494237),
      map: map,
      clickable: true,
      title: 'teste'
  });
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });


        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        //]]>
        </script>  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <nav class="indigo no-pad-bot" role="navigation">
    <div class="container" class="parallax-container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo"></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right side-nav no-pad-bot">
          <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="disabled">Ver denúncias</a></li>
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large fazerdenuncia" style="margin-top: 5px; float: right !important">Fazer denúncia</a>
        </ul><a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div class="section no-pad-bot no-pad-top white" id="index-banner">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col s12 m8">
       <h1>Places to check out in Zagreb</h1>

        <section id="sidebar">
            <div id="directions_panel"></div>
        </section>

        <section id="main">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
        </section>
 </div> 
 <div class="col s12 m4 barra flow-text">
 <h1>
 Últimas denúncias 
 </h1>
  <!-- últimas denuncias -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col s10 m10 offset-s1 offset-m1 z-depth-2 grey lighten-3" id="ultimas-denuncias">
    <h2 class="flow-text">
Nanana </h2>
<h2 class="flow-text">
Teste 2 </h2>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col s10 m10 offset-s1 offset-m1">
<p class="ultimos120">Nos últimos 120 dias</p>
<div class="text-center">
<h5 class="flow-text">55 denúncias feitas</h5>
<h5 class=" flow-text">25 denúncias resolvidas</h5>
</div></div>
 <!-- fim últimas denúncias -->
 </div>
</div>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer grey lighten-2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="black-text">Sobre este site</h5>
          <p class="black-text text-lighten-1">
          Esse site é mantido estudantes do ensino médio para lallalallala. <br> Caso queira contribuir para o projeto, clique <a href="doacao.html">aqui</a> para fazer uma doação.
          </p>


        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="black-text">Links úteis</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="black-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="black-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="black-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="black-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
     <span class="black-text">Feito por</span> <a class="pink-text" href="http://www.mat3.us">mat3.us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Got to make the 2 texts appear, however, both of them appears on the same marker!

```
<?php

$query_map = "SELECT * FROM denuncias ORDER BY id";
$map_executa = mysql_query($query_map);
$lat = -1.456688;
$log = -48.477586;
$Count = 0;
$i = 0;

?>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var map;


        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $lat ?>, <?= $log ?>);

        function init() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


            <?php    while ($map = mysql_fetch_object($map_executa)) { 
              ++$Count; ?>

                  var contentString<?= $Count ?> = '<div id="content" style="height: 200px;">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?= $map->titulo ?></h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<?= $map->descricao ?>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString<?= $Count ?>,
      maxWidth: 400
  });
  var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString1,
      maxWidth: 400
  });


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:  new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $map->lat ?>, <?= $map->log ?>),
      map: map,
      clickable: true,
      title: 'teste'
  });
                          <?php } ?>
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                // Aqui!!!

    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    infowindow1.open(map,marker);
    infowindow2.open(map,marker);

  });



        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        //]]>
        </script>
```

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Whats the delivered source code? Can u post the code your browser shows

Comment: Sure. I'm gonna edit it. I think it's because the var has the same name! Is there anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch the Object first and then do a  `foreach` Loop:

```
<?php 
$Count = 0;
$map = mysql_fetch_object($map_executa) :
foreach($map as $marker)) {
++$Count; //This adds 1 to Count every time ?>
                  var contentString = '<div id="content" style="height: 200px;">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading"><?= $marker->titulo ?></h3>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<?= $marker->descricao ?>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:  new google.maps.LatLng(<?= $marker->lat ?>, <?= $marker->log ?>),
      map: map,
      clickable: true,
      title: 'teste'
  });
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
          <?php } ?>
```

A foreach Loop has a better Performance too. See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php for more Information.

Edit: 
You have to Options:

1) Create a new Variable every time; You just need a Count:

```
var infowindow<?php echo count;?> = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });
```

2) Use an Array: (Im not exactlly sure about the Array Syntax in JS)

```
infowindow() = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });
```

and then call the window with

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(count, marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow(count).open(map,marker);
  });
```

You Need to create an Array for the markers to not just for the infowindows

Comment: Did you just copied my code? I havent tested it of course so there might mebe some Syntax Problems. But as chandra said the Problem is more likely to be in your Javascript.

Comment: I did change it but It didn't work... well, is there anyway to add new variables each loop?

Comment: Hello There!
It's creating two infowindow with the first option, but they both have the same name so It doesn't work...

Comment: you Need to inizialize the var Count and add +1 to it every round. `var $count = 0;` before the loop and in the Loop `++$count;`

Comment: Sorry to bother you... I didn't understand. I create a variable $count that equals 0, and then add 1 to it? but how do I do it? in which part of the code? Sorry

Comment: Hi!
Thank your for helping me. For some reason, with foreach I don't even get a map - so I'm still using while, but the count "function" is not working... :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69493/discussion-between-mateus-guimaraes-and-j-s-stack).

Comment: In my Answer code (the Long one) I havent implement the Count in the JavaScript you Need to add ` <?php echo count;?>` To the marker and infowindow var in javascript

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating the info window object for each iteration, it will always display the last value because it is overriding the object. Try to place the below code outside the while loop and let me know if you have any issues.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400
  });
```

Thank you

Comment: Hello!
It dind't work... Is there the possiblity to put this var inside a loop and add a number each time? I mean
var infowindow
var infowindow2 
...

Comment: You can Create an Array and at a new record to it every time